# Multiple in person signatures in one iframe

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to understand if it is possible to have multiple people sign a document within one iFrame or if a new token needs to be generated (and new iFrame created) for each person who wants to sign.

Currently in my application, I use the Template ID to instantiate a new envelope.  The template has 3 roles: Agent, Client1, and Client 2.

I then request a token for the envelope so it can be viewed in the iFrame.  A screen comes up that says "Chris please give Agent control of the keyboard and mouse" and then that person fills out the document... After that person is done, the iframe forwards to the returnUrl.

I was expecting that after Agent finishes, it would say "Chris please give Client1 control of the keyboard and mouse" - but it does not.

Is there a way to get all roles signing in one flow without regenerating a token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate a new, unique signing token for each individual recipient that will be singing in embedded fashion.

When you use DocuSign's **[Embedding](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#Embedding)** functionality/APIs you are basically telling the DocuSign system that instead of the platform taking care of everything (i.e. generating each signing URL, authenticating the user, email notifications, routing to the next recipient, etc) that your app will manage all of that instead.

Additionally, whenever you generate a signing token that token expires after 5 mins and they also expire after one-use (you need to generate a new one if they close the window, decline to sign, etc).

So having said all that, the only way the system will automatically route to the next recipient in the routing order is if that next recipient does NOT have the `clientUserId` set (i.e. they are not signing using embedding).  If all your recipients are accessing the envelope through Embedding then you'll need to generate a new signing URL for each recipient.

Some additional resources:

- [Embedding API - aka CreateRecipientView](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/)
- [Corresponding API in the API Explorer Tool](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeViews&operations=createRecipient)

Comment: Thanks Ergin, this clears it up and saves me a ton of time researching! :)

Answer (score 1):

Some comments in addition to Ergin's answer:

Try hard to not use an iFrame. Especially if the app may be used on a tablet or mobile. Why: the DocuSign window really needs the entire screen to give a quality signing experience to the signer.

In your use case, your app could have a screen that includes a button "I am George Smith, Client 1. I am ready to sign." And it is important that your agents be trained that George Smith **always** pushes the button. (Never the agent.)

Doing so gives you a stronger case that it was George Smith who signed.

When the button is pushed, your app would retrieve the recipientView URL from DocuSign and redirect to it.

When DocuSign redirects back to your app after signing, your app can show a screen "Susan Smith, Client 2 is ready to sign" (If George actually signed. See the `event` query parameter. [Docs.](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/#/definitions/recipientViewRequest))

**Authentication**

The most important issue when using embedded signing is authentication. Your app is responsible for guaranteeing the authentication of the signer(s). You need to carefully understand how you will do that.

In the case of an agent and clients in person, will the agent be checking government issued ID? If so, you may want to have the agent, as part of her signing process, attest that they checked the clients' government ID.

Because of the attestation issue, it often makes sense for the agent's signature to be last. That way the attestation can be something like "I affirm that I checked the government ID of the signers George Smith and Susan Smith." (Ask your lawyer for exact wording.)

You can use the ["Initial Here" tab type](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeTabs/) next to the attestation.